# How to read auto-filled username/password from a form using Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, autofill

Right now I have a form that has two input: username and password. If I typed them manually, my validation function can pick up the values. However, if the values are filled by broswer's autofill feature. Ember cannot get the value due to no event is fired. 
So I have this code (from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324473/browser-autofill-databinding`):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.TextField.reopen({
  triggerEvents: function () {
    Ember.run.next(this, function () {
      this.$().trigger("change");
    });
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

And I imported it into app.js

Somehow, it is still not working. Will `didInsertElement` be triggered by autofill? I am not sure.

I use `this.get('xxx')` to get the values.

If you have a better way to allow ember detect autofill. I am open to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add observer for form fields.
Example:

```
// app/components/test-form.js
import Component from '@ember/component';
    export default Component.extend({
      isChanged: Ember.observer('login', 'password', function() {
        this.validate();
      }),
      validate() {
        let login = this.get('login');
        let password = this.get('password');
        console.log('validate', login, password);
      },
      actions: {
        submit() {
          console.log('submit');
        }
      }
    });


// app/templates/components/test-form.hbs
<form>
  <label>Login
  {{input type="text" value=login change='validate' }}
  </label>
  <label>Password
  {{input type="password" value=password change='validate' }}
  </label>
  <button {{action 'submit'}}>Click</button>
</form>
```

PS. Tested in Firefox only.

Comment: Hi, I dont have a Component for the form, but I have a controller. I tested your code in the controller but it does not work. Do I have to use component?

Comment: The same approach is suitable for controller too, and component is not required